# setting google chart multiple axes from dynamically generated data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to replicate the following code from a working [example](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/google-charts-double-axes.html):

```
 series: {0: {targetAxisIndex:0},
          1: {targetAxisIndex:0},
          2: {targetAxisIndex:1},
```

This is for setting which y-axis is used to plot different columns from a dataTable on a Google chart.

However I have a variable number of columns (based on user input), therefore am collecting an array of the required axis (the axisAssignment Array in the below example).

My code is below:

```
var series = {};

        for (i=0;i<axisAssignment.length;i++)
        {
            series[i] = {targetAxisIndex: axisAssignment[i]};
        }
        return series;
```

However, all of my data is only being written to the left axis, despite the debugger suggesting that the object is correct. My option code is below:

```
var options = 
{    
    hAxis: {title: xTitle},
    vAxes: {0: {title: y1Type},
            1: {title: y2Type}
            },        
    series: calculateSeries(),
    pointSize: 1,
    legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}}
};
```

Any assistance would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks

Tom

edit: whole file for reference (it's a work in progress so a bit of a mess I'm afraid)

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

function drawChart() 
{

    var title = "Node: "+currentNode;
    var xTitle = "Date";
    var yTitle = titles[currentVariable];
    if (totalData !== null)
    {
        var tempData = newData();
        var tempData2 = totalData;
        dataArray[dataCount] = tempData;
        var joinMark = countArray(dataCount);
        totalData = google.visualization.data.join(tempData2,tempData,'full',[[0,0]],joinMark,[1]);
        dataCount = dataCount+1;
    }
    else
    {
        totalData = newData();
        dataArray[dataCount] =  totalData; 
        dataCount = 1;
    }
    var options = 
    {

        hAxis: {title: xTitle},
        vAxes: {0: {title: y1Type},
                1: {title: y2Type}
                },        
        series: calculateSeries(),
        pointSize: 0.5,
        legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}}
        };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('graph'));
    console.log(calculateSeries());
    chart.draw(totalData, options);

    function countArray(count)
    {
        var arrayCount= new Array();
        if (count===1)
        {
            arrayCount[0] = count;
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
                {
                    var temp = i+1;
                    arrayCount[i] = temp;
                }
        }
        return arrayCount;
    }

function calculateSeries()
    {
        var series = {};

        for (i=0;i<axisAssignment.length;i++)
        {
            series[i] = {targetAxisIndex: axisAssignment[i]};
        }
        return series;
    }

function newData()
{
    var dataType = dataIn[0];
    dataIn.shift();
    var axis = dataSelect(dataType);
    axisAssignment.push(axis);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', "Node: "+currentNode+": "+titles[currentVariable]);
    var num = (dataIn.length);
    data.addRows(num/2);
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i<num)

    {
        var d = (dataIn[i]);
        if (i%2===0)
        {
            d = new Date(d);
            data.setCell(j,0,d);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            data.setCell(j,1,parseFloat(d));                
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
function dataSelect(type)
{
    var axisNumber;
    if (y1Type === null || y1Type === type)
    {
        y1Type = type;
        axisNumber = 0;
    }
    else if (y2Type === null || y2Type === type)
    {
        y2Type = type;
        axisNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You already have 2 axes assigned.\n\nPlease clear the graph \nor select more objects of \ntype"+y1Type+" or \ntype "+y2Type+" to continue.");
        axisNumber = null;
    }
    return axisNumber;
}

}
```

Comment: The problem doesn´t seem to be in the code you have posted, as it worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n7ud7s39/

Comment: Ok thanks, is there anywhere else that might be causing this problem?

Comment: Well, you should do a console.log(calculateSeries()) to check if its generating the right options

Comment: interestingly, hardcoding with my test example fails to place the 3rd column in the correct axis. i've uploaded the whole javascript file to my oringal question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that it's an issue with my choice of ScatterChart,

```
var options = 
{
    hAxis: {title: xTitle},         
    series: calculateSeries(),
    vAxes: {0: {title: y1Type },
            1: {title: y2Type}
           },  
   pointSize: 0.5,
   legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}}
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('graph'));
chart.draw(totalData, options);
```

I've changed it to LineChart and it's working fine, by keeping the pointSize option, the appearance is almost completely unchanged. Thanks for your help juvian.

Comment: oh, didn't notice it was a ScatterChart. Yeah, if you check on documentation ScatterChart doesn't support targetAxisIndex, you can check that in the series configuration options. Linechart does say that targetAxisIndex is an option of series